# Throwable.initCause() and setting the cause by constructor : why are we limited to set a single time the cause?

Tags: java

Why can we call `Throwable.initCause()` only once on a `Throwable`/`Exception` object ?
And why if the cause exception was set by a constructor, then can we not set it again using `initCause()`?
Can we set more than one cause for an exception ?

Comment: Because you can't have two causes?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51568806/85421

Comment: @shiv kumar You should probably deleted this one : stackoverflow.com/q/51568806/85421

Answer (score 4):

> Why can we call Throwable.initCause() only once on a
>   Throwable/Exception object ? And why if the cause exception was set by
>   a constructor, then can we not set it again using initCause()?

`Throwable.initCause()` allows us to instantiate an exception with a constructor that doesn't set the cause exception and to set in a second time the cause of the exception :

```
MyException e = new MyException();
e.initCause(rootException);
```

Or :

```
MyException e = new MyException("error message...");
e.initCause(rootException);
```

So you have to consider it as an alternative to the arg constructor that accepts the cause exception as parameter :

```
MyException e = new MyException(rootException);
```

You can set the cause exception a single time because it is not designed to be modified : **if an exception was thrown for a cause, the cause will not change then.**
So providing this possibility to client classes could be error prone.
But the language designers would also allow to set the cause exception even as  the exception class that we want to instantiate doesn't provide a constructor that accepts as parameter the cause exception. So they introduced `initCause()`.
But in the very most of cases, you don't want to use this method. Invoking a arg constructor that passes the exception cause is simpler and straighter.

> Can we set more than one cause for an exception ?

No it is not possible : a**n exception may occur because of a single direct exception**.
But an exception could be caused by multiple intermediaries/previous thrown exception.
So you can chain exceptions beyond 2 as shown in the previous example :

```
MyException e = new MyException(rootException);
```

For example suppose `a()` calls `b()` that calls `c()` and each method may throw an exception if something wrong happens :

```
void a(){  
    try{
        b();
    }
    catch(SecondException e){
       throw new ThirdException(e);
    }    
}

void b(){        
    try{
        c();
    }
    catch(FirstException e){
       throw new SecondException(e);
    }
}

void c(){
     throw new FirstException();
}
```

If all of these methods throw their exception, you get 3 chained exceptions in the final stacktrace of `ThirdException` :
`ThirdException` caused by `SecondException` caused `FirstException`.
It is like if you had written :

```
new ThirdException(new SecondException(new FirstException()));
```

but with as bonus the snapshot of the execution stack of the thread for each created exception.

Comment: Hey :) What you said is both funny and pleasant : thanks :)  It is right that we have each a different writing style. Approximate English and long sentences, it is unmistakably david :) You  are right for the question.  I will fix it :)

Comment: It is a serious compliment! I find your text to be well written and balancing facts and explanations.

Comment: @GhostCat So I will take it as you offered me :)  But to be honest I prefer your style. I have sometimes the feeling to read a native English spoken  : you are great :) And also I like very much the way which you pull the subject.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a choice of design. I don't know the original authors from Sun/Oracle, but the overall design of exceptions seems to be that they should be treated as immutable objects. If you think about it, it actually makes sense - if the exceptions could change after they were created, that would surely make any debugging a nightmare!